# Problems when executing SQL Where statement with a date

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

When I hardcode the values and execute the SQL statement within Access 2010, the command is executed and the values required are returned.

`SELECT [Event ID], [Crowd Size], [Event Name]
FROM Event
WHERE ([Event Date]=#8/11/2012#) AND ([Event Name]="Peter")`

However when I use text boxes in place of the hardcoded values

`("SELECT [Event ID], [Crowd Size], [Event Name] FROM [Event] WHERE ([Event Name]='" + textBoxEventName.Text + "') AND ([Event Date]=#" + textBoxEventDate.Text + "#)");`

When trying to read from the datareader, it is unable to do so as there doesn't seem to be any values in there.

I have gone through the code in debug mode and the values in the text boxes are correct, but still doesn't happen.

Comment: Have you checked the result of the string concatenation?

Comment: Try assigning your sql string to a text variable and check using the debugger that it is as you expect.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Access since this is before it hits the database.  This is going from VS form to whatever function is generating the sql. May want to step through to see what's going on.  Have you tried textboxEventDate.Text.ToString("formathere")?

Comment: @adrianbanks I have assigned the textbox contents to a string variable, the debug mode shows the values as it should, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @phoog I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: @PeterRoche: I didn't mean assign the textbox contents to a variable, I meant assign the whole sql statement including the textbox values. I suspect you have an extra space (or something similar) causing your query to not work properly.

Comment: "check the result of the string concatenation" = "assign the sql string to a variable and check it using the debugger", so it was the same suggestion as adrianbanks's. Another thought -- do the event names contain apostrophes? I've added the ms-access tag; perhaps this will attract the attention of someone who knows more than I do about the different SQL dialects that Access supports.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for your suggestion, but i think I may have figured out the problem, for some reason Access is designed allbackwards, and seems to work when i put the date in YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: @PeterRoche is 8/11 the 11th of August or the 8th of November? Access SQL interprets ambiguous dates as month/day/year regardless of the locale; supplying an unambiguous format like year-month-day would avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of fiddling around with this problem,

The solution is that Access SQL likes dates in the format

```
#YYYY/MM/DD#
```

Answer (score 1):

Access is a bit tricky with the SQL Queries that it runs...

Make sure that the date you are grabbing is in the correct format, or assign it a format your-self.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx (Standard Date and Time Format Strings)

also make sure that there are all the quotation marks necessary and that you are not using any of the "reserved words"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335 (List of reserved words in Access)

Comment: [Event Date] is a Date/Time field presumably.  Check that it has nothing to do with the time component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: see this page: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlselect.php